# How to disable github device tracking and email verification on signin without 2FA?

Tags: github

2FA is already disabled, Github is asking for email on every signin.

I am traveling for the next few years so nearly every time I sign in will be from a different location, device, or even country. I do not care if my account is hacked, the hacker can have it for their prudence and being able to guess a 16 character random alphanumeric password that is stored nowhere but my own head. I only care about my time saved.

If they can hack my github account, they can hack my email, so it is not making me more secure, it is only stealing my time and making me spend a couple minutes every sign in which is annoying.

The email from github says to enable 2 factor authentication to disable 2 factor authentication (email is a 2 factor authentication, technically, 2-step verification). That is stupid, all they are saying is either save your device and add an extra step a differnt way.

I want no authentication but my password, just 1-step signin. When I sign in, I don't want any checks. I don't want my location stored or tracked. I don't want any verification no matter who I am or what my location, IP, or device is.

The point is, to disable 2 steps with email, you need 2 steps another way. I want 1 step login.

How can I disable email 2 factor authentication without enabling a different form of 2 factor authentication?

Comment: Use another product and hope Microsoft doesn't buy it too.

Comment: I thought about it and if you're bitter enough, you could design your own app and use a personal access token so you won't have to deal with it.